# Событие когда кнопка на клавиатуре/мыши не нажата pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, клавиатура

Когда кнопка нажата цвет фона и текста меняются. Как поменять обратно когда она не нажата?

Т.е. если нажать кнопку на клавиатуре, то подсветится соответствующая ей, как сделать чтобы при отпускании она снова становилась черного цвета(текст)?

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(950, 413)
        MainWindow.setAnimated(True)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.keyboard = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.keyboard.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, -30, 681, 351))
        self.keyboard.setText("")
        self.keyboard.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../Downloads/f.png"))
        self.keyboard.setObjectName("keyboard")
        self.f1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f1.setObjectName("f1")
        self.f4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f4.setObjectName("f4")
        self.f3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f3.setObjectName("f3")
        self.f2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f2.setObjectName("f2")
        self.esc = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.esc.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 21, 31))
        self.esc.setObjectName("esc")
        self.f5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f5.setObjectName("f5")
        self.f6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f6.setObjectName("f6")
        self.f7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f7.setObjectName("f7")
        self.W = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.W.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 90, 21, 31))
        self.W.setObjectName("W")
        self.S = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.S.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 130, 21, 31))
        self.S.setObjectName("S")
        self.A = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.A.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 130, 21, 31))
        self.A.setObjectName("A")
        self.D = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.D.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 130, 21, 31))
        self.D.setObjectName("D")
        self.Ctrl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Ctrl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 220, 21, 31))
        self.Ctrl.setObjectName("Ctrl")
        self.Alt = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Alt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 220, 21, 31))
        self.Alt.setObjectName("Alt")
        self.Win = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Win.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 220, 21, 31))
        self.Win.setObjectName("Win")
        self.ShifL = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.ShifL.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 180, 81, 21))
        self.ShifL.setObjectName("ShifL")
        self.Enter = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Enter.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 130, 41, 31))
        self.Enter.setObjectName("Enter")
        self.Backspace = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Backspace.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(570, 50, 41, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.Backspace.setFont(font)
        self.Backspace.setObjectName("Backspace")
        self.dlt = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.dlt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 20, 21, 31))
        self.dlt.setObjectName("dlt")
        self.Tab = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Tab.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 90, 41, 31))
        self.Tab.setObjectName("Tab")
        self.tild = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.tild.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 50, 21, 31))
        self.tild.setObjectName("tild")
        self.ShiftR = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.ShiftR.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 180, 71, 21))
        self.ShiftR.setObjectName("ShiftR")
        self.F = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.F.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 130, 21, 31))
        self.F.setObjectName("F")
        self.G = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.G.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 130, 21, 31))
        self.G.setObjectName("G")
        self.H = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.H.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 130, 21, 31))
        self.H.setObjectName("H")
        self.J = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.J.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 130, 21, 31))
        self.J.setObjectName("J")
        self.K = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.K.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 130, 21, 31))
        self.K.setObjectName("K")
        self.L = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.L.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 130, 21, 31))
        self.L.setObjectName("L")
        self.colon = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.colon.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 130, 21, 31))
        self.colon.setObjectName("colon")
        self.quatmark = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.quatmark.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 130, 21, 31))
        self.quatmark.setObjectName("quatmark")
        self.Z = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Z.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 170, 21, 31))
        self.Z.setObjectName("Z")
        self.X = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.X.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 170, 21, 31))
        self.X.setObjectName("X")
        self.C = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.C.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 170, 21, 31))
        self.C.setObjectName("C")
        self.V = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.V.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 170, 21, 31))
        self.V.setObjectName("V")
        self.B = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.B.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 170, 21, 31))
        self.B.setObjectName("B")
        self.N = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.N.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 170, 21, 31))
        self.N.setObjectName("N")
        self.M = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.M.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 170, 21, 31))
        self.M.setObjectName("M")
        self.rig = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.rig.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 170, 21, 31))
        self.rig.setObjectName("rig")
        self.lef = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lef.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(450, 170, 21, 31))
        self.lef.setObjectName("lef")
        self.questmark = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.questmark.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 170, 21, 31))
        self.questmark.setObjectName("questmark")
        self.AltR = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.AltR.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 220, 21, 31))
        self.AltR.setObjectName("AltR")
        self.CtrlR = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.CtrlR.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 220, 21, 31))
        self.CtrlR.setObjectName("CtrlR")
        self.up = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.up.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 210, 16, 16))
        self.up.setObjectName("up")
        self.down = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.down.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 230, 21, 21))
        self.down.setObjectName("down")
        self.left = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.left.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 230, 21, 31))
        self.left.setObjectName("left")
        self.right = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.right.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 230, 21, 31))
        self.right.setObjectName("right")
        self.CapsLock = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.CapsLock.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 140, 61, 31))
        self.CapsLock.setObjectName("CapsLock")
        self.Q = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Q.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 90, 21, 31))
        self.Q.setObjectName("Q")
        self.E = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.E.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 90, 21, 31))
        self.E.setObjectName("E")
        self.R = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.R.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 90, 21, 31))
        self.R.setObjectName("R")
        self.T = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.T.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 90, 21, 31))
        self.T.setObjectName("T")
        self.Y = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Y.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 90, 21, 31))
        self.Y.setObjectName("Y")
        self.U = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.U.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 90, 21, 31))
        self.U.setObjectName("U")
        self.I = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.I.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 90, 21, 31))
        self.I.setObjectName("I")
        self.O = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.O.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 90, 21, 31))
        self.O.setObjectName("O")
        self.P = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.P.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 90, 21, 31))
        self.P.setObjectName("P")
        self.curlybrace1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.curlybrace1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 90, 21, 31))
        self.curlybrace1.setObjectName("curlybrace1")
        self.curlybrace2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.curlybrace2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 90, 20, 31))
        self.curlybrace2.setObjectName("curlybrace2")
        self.revslash = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.revslash.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 90, 31, 31))
        self.revslash.setObjectName("revslash")
        self.n1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.n1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 50, 21, 31))
        self.n1.setObjectName("n1")
        self.n2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.n2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 50, 21, 31))
        self.n2.setObjectName("n2")
        self.n3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.n3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 50, 21, 31))
        self.n3.setObjectName("n3")
        self.n4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.n4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 50, 21, 31))
        self.n4.setObjectName("n4")
        self.n5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.n5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 50, 21, 31))
        self.n5.setObjectName("n5")
        self.n6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.n6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 50, 21, 31))
        self.n6.setObjectName("n6")
        self.n7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.n7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 50, 21, 31))
        self.n7.setObjectName("n7")
        self.n8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.n8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 50, 21, 31))
        self.n8.setObjectName("n8")
        self.n9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.n9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 50, 21, 31))
        self.n9.setObjectName("n9")
        self.n0 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.n0.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 50, 21, 31))
        self.n0.setObjectName("n0")
        self.dash = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.dash.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 50, 21, 31))
        self.dash.setObjectName("dash")
        self.plus = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.plus.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 50, 21, 31))
        self.plus.setObjectName("plus")
        self.f8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f8.setObjectName("f8")
        self.f9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f9.setObjectName("f9")
        self.f10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f10.setObjectName("f10")
        self.f11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f11.setObjectName("f11")
        self.f12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f12.setObjectName("f12")
        self.mouse = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.mouse.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 0, 401, 361))
        self.mouse.setText("")
        self.mouse.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("255016A1.png"))
        self.mouse.setObjectName("mouse")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(700, 80, 71, 111))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.rightbuttonmouse = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.rightbuttonmouse.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(800, 80, 71, 111))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.rightbuttonmouse.setFont(font)
        self.rightbuttonmouse.setObjectName("rightbuttonmouse")
        self.middlebuttonmouse = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.middlebuttonmouse.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(779, 50, 17, 57))
        self.middlebuttonmouse.setText("")
        self.middlebuttonmouse.setObjectName("middlebuttonmouse")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 950, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "skolkovo"))
        self.f1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F1"))
        self.f4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F4"))
        self.f3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F3"))
        self.f2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F2"))
        self.esc.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Esc"))
        self.f5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F5"))
        self.f6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F6"))
        self.f7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F7"))
        self.W.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "W"))
        self.S.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "S"))
        self.A.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "A"))
        self.D.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "D"))
        self.Ctrl.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ctrl"))
        self.Alt.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Alt"))
        self.Win.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Win"))
        self.ShifL.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Shift ⇫"))
        self.Enter.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "↵ Enter"))
        self.Backspace.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "⇽"))
        self.dlt.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Dlt"))
        self.Tab.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Tab ⭾"))
        self.tild.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "`"))
        self.ShiftR.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Shift"))
        self.F.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F"))
        self.G.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "G"))
        self.H.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "H"))
        self.J.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "J"))
        self.K.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " K"))
        self.L.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " L"))
        self.colon.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " : ;"))
        self.quatmark.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "\""))
        self.Z.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Z"))
        self.X.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "X"))
        self.C.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "C"))
        self.V.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "V"))
        self.B.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "B"))
        self.N.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "N"))
        self.M.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "M"))
        self.rig.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<"))
        self.lef.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ">"))
        self.questmark.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "?"))
        self.AltR.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Alt"))
        self.CtrlR.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ctrl"))
        self.up.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " ↑"))
        self.down.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " ↓"))
        self.left.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "←"))
        self.right.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "→"))
        self.CapsLock.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Caps Lock"))
        self.Q.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Q"))
        self.E.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "E"))
        self.R.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "R"))
        self.T.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "T"))
        self.Y.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Y"))
        self.U.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "U"))
        self.I.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " I"))
        self.O.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " O"))
        self.P.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "P"))
        self.curlybrace1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " {"))
        self.curlybrace2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "}"))
        self.revslash.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "| \\"))
        self.n1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.n2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.n3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.n4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.n5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.n6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.n7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "7"))
        self.n8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "8"))
        self.n9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "9"))
        self.n0.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.dash.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "- _"))
        self.plus.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "+ ="))
        self.f8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F8"))
        self.f9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F9"))
        self.f10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F10"))
        self.f11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F11"))
        self.f12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F12"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "   ЛКМ"))
        self.rightbuttonmouse.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "  ПКМ"))


keymap = {}
for key, value in vars(Qt).items():
    if isinstance(value, Qt.Key):
        keymap[value] = key.partition('_')[2]

modmap = {
    Qt.ControlModifier: keymap[Qt.Key_Control],
    Qt.AltModifier: keymap[Qt.Key_Alt],
    Qt.ShiftModifier: keymap[Qt.Key_Shift],
    Qt.MetaModifier: keymap[Qt.Key_Meta],
    Qt.GroupSwitchModifier: keymap[Qt.Key_AltGr],
    Qt.KeypadModifier: keymap[Qt.Key_NumLock],
}


class Example(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.prev_key = []

    def mousePressEvent(self, ev):
        if ev.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.label, ]
        elif ev.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            self.rightbuttonmouse.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.rightbuttonmouse, ]
        elif ev.button() == Qt.MiddleButton:
            self.middlebuttonmouse.setStyleSheet("background-color: red; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.middlebuttonmouse, ]

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        _key, _keys = self.keyevent_to_string(event)
        # раскомментируйте строку  ниже, чтобы увидеть что происходит
        print(f'------> {_key}, {event.text()}, {event.key()}, {_keys}')

        key = event.key()

        if self.prev_key:
            for k in self.prev_key:
                k.setStyleSheet("")

        if _keys[0] == 'Control' and key == Qt.Key_W:
            print(f'Нажали: {_key}')
            self.W.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.Ctrl.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Ctrl, self.W]
            # ...
        elif _keys[0] == 'Alt' and key == Qt.Key_W:
            print(f'Нажали: {_key}')
            self.W.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.Alt.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Alt, self.W]
            # ...
        elif _keys[0] == 'Shift' and key == Qt.Key_W:
            print(f'Нажали: {_key}')
            self.W.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.ShifL.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.ShifL, self.W]
            # ...

        elif key == Qt.Key_W:
            print('Нажали: w')
            self.W.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.W, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_A:
            print('Нажали: a')
            self.A.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.A, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_S:
            print('Нажали: s')
            self.S.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.S, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_D:
            print('Нажали: d')
            self.D.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.D, ]
            # ...
        elif key == Qt.Key_Escape:
            print('Нажали: Escape')
            self.esc.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.esc, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Tab:
            print('Нажали: Tab')
            self.Tab.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Tab, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Backspace:
            print('Нажали: Backspace')
            self.Backspace.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Backspace, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Enter:  # Обычно находится на клавиатуре.
            print('Нажали: Enter')
            self.Enter.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Enter, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Return:
            print('Нажали: Enter/Return')
            self.Enter.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Enter, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_QuoteLeft:
            print('Нажали: A_10/QuoteLeft(`)')
            self.A_10.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.A_10, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Delete:
            print('Нажали: Delete')
            self.dlt.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.dlt, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Shift:
            print('Нажали: Shift')
            self.ShifL.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.ShiftR.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.ShifL, self.ShiftR]
            time.sleep(60)
            self.ShifL.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.ShiftR.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.ShifL, self.ShiftR]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Control:  # В macOS это соответствует клавишам Command.
            print('Нажали: Ctrl')
            self.Ctrl.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Ctrl, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Alt:
            print('Нажали: Alt')
            self.Alt.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Alt, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Meta:
            print('Нажали: Windows ')
            self.Win.setStyleSheet(" color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Win, ]

    def keyevent_to_string(self, event):
        sequence = []
        for modifier, text in modmap.items():
            if event.modifiers() & modifier:
                sequence.append(text)
        key = keymap.get(event.key(), event.text())
        if key not in sequence:
            sequence.append(key)
        return '+'.join(sequence), sequence


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: уточните пожалуйста лучше. что вы хотите сделать? О какой кнопке идет речь ?

Comment: На клавиатуре есть кнопки любую из них

Comment: Если нажать кнопку на клавиатуре то подсветится соответсвующая ей, как сделать чтобы при отпускании она снова становилась черного цвета(текст)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, вы можете получить желаемый эффект используя таймер. Попробуйте поиграться с  интервалом тайм-аута в миллисекундах.

Класс `QTimer` предоставляет повторяющиеся и однократные таймеры. 
Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html

```
import sys
# ? import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(950, 413)
        MainWindow.setAnimated(True)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.keyboard = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.keyboard.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, -30, 681, 351))
        self.keyboard.setText("?")
#        self.keyboard.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../Downloads/f.png"))
        self.keyboard.setObjectName("keyboard")
        self.f1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f1.setObjectName("f1")
        self.f4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f4.setObjectName("f4")
        self.f3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f3.setObjectName("f3")
        self.f2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f2.setObjectName("f2")
        self.esc = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.esc.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 21, 31))
        self.esc.setObjectName("esc")
        self.f5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f5.setObjectName("f5")
        self.f6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f6.setObjectName("f6")
        self.f7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f7.setObjectName("f7")
        self.W = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.W.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 90, 21, 31))
        self.W.setObjectName("W")
        self.S = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.S.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 130, 21, 31))
        self.S.setObjectName("S")
        self.A = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.A.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 130, 21, 31))
        self.A.setObjectName("A")
        self.D = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.D.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 130, 21, 31))
        self.D.setObjectName("D")
        self.Ctrl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Ctrl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 220, 21, 31))
        self.Ctrl.setObjectName("Ctrl")
        self.Alt = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Alt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 220, 21, 31))
        self.Alt.setObjectName("Alt")
        self.Win = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Win.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 220, 21, 31))
        self.Win.setObjectName("Win")
        self.ShifL = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.ShifL.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 180, 81, 21))
        self.ShifL.setObjectName("ShifL")
        self.Enter = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Enter.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 130, 41, 31))
        self.Enter.setObjectName("Enter")
        self.Backspace = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Backspace.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(570, 50, 41, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.Backspace.setFont(font)
        self.Backspace.setObjectName("Backspace")
        self.dlt = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.dlt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 20, 21, 31))
        self.dlt.setObjectName("dlt")
        self.Tab = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Tab.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 90, 41, 31))
        self.Tab.setObjectName("Tab")
        self.tild = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.tild.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 50, 21, 31))
        self.tild.setObjectName("tild")
        self.ShiftR = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.ShiftR.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 180, 71, 21))
        self.ShiftR.setObjectName("ShiftR")
        self.F = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.F.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 130, 21, 31))
        self.F.setObjectName("F")
        self.G = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.G.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 130, 21, 31))
        self.G.setObjectName("G")
        self.H = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.H.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 130, 21, 31))
        self.H.setObjectName("H")
        self.J = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.J.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 130, 21, 31))
        self.J.setObjectName("J")
        self.K = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.K.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 130, 21, 31))
        self.K.setObjectName("K")
        self.L = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.L.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 130, 21, 31))
        self.L.setObjectName("L")
        self.colon = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.colon.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 130, 21, 31))
        self.colon.setObjectName("colon")
        self.quatmark = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.quatmark.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 130, 21, 31))
        self.quatmark.setObjectName("quatmark")
        self.Z = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Z.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 170, 21, 31))
        self.Z.setObjectName("Z")
        self.X = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.X.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 170, 21, 31))
        self.X.setObjectName("X")
        self.C = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.C.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 170, 21, 31))
        self.C.setObjectName("C")
        self.V = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.V.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 170, 21, 31))
        self.V.setObjectName("V")
        self.B = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.B.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 170, 21, 31))
        self.B.setObjectName("B")
        self.N = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.N.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 170, 21, 31))
        self.N.setObjectName("N")
        self.M = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.M.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 170, 21, 31))
        self.M.setObjectName("M")
        self.rig = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.rig.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 170, 21, 31))
        self.rig.setObjectName("rig")
        self.lef = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lef.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(450, 170, 21, 31))
        self.lef.setObjectName("lef")
        self.questmark = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.questmark.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 170, 21, 31))
        self.questmark.setObjectName("questmark")
        self.AltR = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.AltR.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 220, 21, 31))
        self.AltR.setObjectName("AltR")
        self.CtrlR = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.CtrlR.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 220, 21, 31))
        self.CtrlR.setObjectName("CtrlR")
        self.up = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.up.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 210, 16, 16))
        self.up.setObjectName("up")
        self.down = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.down.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 230, 21, 21))
        self.down.setObjectName("down")
        self.left = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.left.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 230, 21, 31))
        self.left.setObjectName("left")
        self.right = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.right.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 230, 21, 31))
        self.right.setObjectName("right")
        self.CapsLock = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.CapsLock.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 140, 61, 31))
        self.CapsLock.setObjectName("CapsLock")
        self.Q = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Q.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 90, 21, 31))
        self.Q.setObjectName("Q")
        self.E = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.E.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 90, 21, 31))
        self.E.setObjectName("E")
        self.R = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.R.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 90, 21, 31))
        self.R.setObjectName("R")
        self.T = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.T.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 90, 21, 31))
        self.T.setObjectName("T")
        self.Y = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Y.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 90, 21, 31))
        self.Y.setObjectName("Y")
        self.U = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.U.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 90, 21, 31))
        self.U.setObjectName("U")
        self.I = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.I.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 90, 21, 31))
        self.I.setObjectName("I")
        self.O = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.O.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 90, 21, 31))
        self.O.setObjectName("O")
        self.P = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.P.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 90, 21, 31))
        self.P.setObjectName("P")
        self.curlybrace1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.curlybrace1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 90, 21, 31))
        self.curlybrace1.setObjectName("curlybrace1")
        self.curlybrace2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.curlybrace2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 90, 20, 31))
        self.curlybrace2.setObjectName("curlybrace2")
        self.revslash = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.revslash.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 90, 31, 31))
        self.revslash.setObjectName("revslash")
        self.n1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.n1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 50, 21, 31))
        self.n1.setObjectName("n1")
        self.n2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.n2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 50, 21, 31))
        self.n2.setObjectName("n2")
        self.n3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.n3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 50, 21, 31))
        self.n3.setObjectName("n3")
        self.n4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.n4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 50, 21, 31))
        self.n4.setObjectName("n4")
        self.n5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.n5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 50, 21, 31))
        self.n5.setObjectName("n5")
        self.n6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.n6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 50, 21, 31))
        self.n6.setObjectName("n6")
        self.n7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.n7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 50, 21, 31))
        self.n7.setObjectName("n7")
        self.n8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.n8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 50, 21, 31))
        self.n8.setObjectName("n8")
        self.n9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.n9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 50, 21, 31))
        self.n9.setObjectName("n9")
        self.n0 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.n0.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 50, 21, 31))
        self.n0.setObjectName("n0")
        self.dash = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.dash.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 50, 21, 31))
        self.dash.setObjectName("dash")
        self.plus = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.plus.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 50, 21, 31))
        self.plus.setObjectName("plus")
        self.f8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f8.setObjectName("f8")
        self.f9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f9.setObjectName("f9")
        self.f10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f10.setObjectName("f10")
        self.f11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f11.setObjectName("f11")
        self.f12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.f12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 20, 21, 31))
        self.f12.setObjectName("f12")
        self.mouse = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.mouse.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 0, 401, 361))
        self.mouse.setText("??")
#        self.mouse.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("255016A1.png"))
        self.mouse.setObjectName("mouse")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(700, 80, 71, 111))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.rightbuttonmouse = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.rightbuttonmouse.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(800, 80, 71, 111))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.rightbuttonmouse.setFont(font)
        self.rightbuttonmouse.setObjectName("rightbuttonmouse")
        self.middlebuttonmouse = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.middlebuttonmouse.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(779, 50, 17, 57))
        self.middlebuttonmouse.setText("")
        self.middlebuttonmouse.setObjectName("middlebuttonmouse")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 950, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "skolkovo"))
        self.f1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F1"))
        self.f4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F4"))
        self.f3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F3"))
        self.f2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F2"))
        self.esc.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Esc"))
        self.f5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F5"))
        self.f6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F6"))
        self.f7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F7"))
        self.W.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "W"))
        self.S.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "S"))
        self.A.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "A"))
        self.D.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "D"))
        self.Ctrl.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ctrl"))
        self.Alt.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Alt"))
        self.Win.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Win"))
        self.ShifL.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Shift"))          # ⇫"))          ?
        self.Enter.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter"))          # "↵ Enter"))   ?
        self.Backspace.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Backspace"))  # "⇽"))         ?
        self.dlt.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Dlt"))
        self.Tab.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Tab"))              #  ⭾"))         ?
        self.tild.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "`"))
        self.ShiftR.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Shift"))
        self.F.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F"))
        self.G.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "G"))
        self.H.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "H"))
        self.J.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "J"))
        self.K.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " K"))
        self.L.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " L"))
        self.colon.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " : ;"))
        self.quatmark.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "\""))
        self.Z.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Z"))
        self.X.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "X"))
        self.C.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "C"))
        self.V.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "V"))
        self.B.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "B"))
        self.N.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "N"))
        self.M.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "M"))
        self.rig.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<"))
        self.lef.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ">"))
        self.questmark.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "?"))
        self.AltR.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Alt"))
        self.CtrlR.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ctrl"))
        self.up.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " ↑"))
        self.down.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " ↓"))
        self.left.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "←"))
        self.right.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "→"))
        self.CapsLock.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Caps Lock"))
        self.Q.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Q"))
        self.E.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "E"))
        self.R.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "R"))
        self.T.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "T"))
        self.Y.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Y"))
        self.U.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "U"))
        self.I.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " I"))
        self.O.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " O"))
        self.P.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "P"))
        self.curlybrace1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " {"))
        self.curlybrace2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "}"))
        self.revslash.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "| \\"))
        self.n1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.n2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.n3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.n4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.n5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.n6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.n7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "7"))
        self.n8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "8"))
        self.n9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "9"))
        self.n0.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.dash.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "- _"))
        self.plus.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "+ ="))
        self.f8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F8"))
        self.f9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F9"))
        self.f10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F10"))
        self.f11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F11"))
        self.f12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F12"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "   ЛКМ"))
        self.rightbuttonmouse.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "  ПКМ"))


keymap = {}
for key, value in vars(Qt).items():
    if isinstance(value, Qt.Key):
        keymap[value] = key.partition('_')[2]

modmap = {
    Qt.ControlModifier: keymap[Qt.Key_Control],
    Qt.AltModifier: keymap[Qt.Key_Alt],
    Qt.ShiftModifier: keymap[Qt.Key_Shift],
    Qt.MetaModifier: keymap[Qt.Key_Meta],
    Qt.GroupSwitchModifier: keymap[Qt.Key_AltGr],
    Qt.KeypadModifier: keymap[Qt.Key_NumLock],
}


class Example(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.prev_key = []

# +++  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv       
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_timer)
        self.timer.start(500)                    
       
    def update_timer(self):
        if self.prev_key:
            for k in self.prev_key:
                k.setStyleSheet("")           
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.label, ]
        elif event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            self.rightbuttonmouse.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.rightbuttonmouse, ]
        elif event.button() == Qt.MiddleButton:
            self.middlebuttonmouse.setStyleSheet("background-color: red; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.middlebuttonmouse, ]

# +++  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv       
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.label.setStyleSheet("")
        elif event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            self.rightbuttonmouse.setStyleSheet("")
        elif event.button() == Qt.MiddleButton:
            self.middlebuttonmouse.setStyleSheet("")
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        _key, _keys = self.keyevent_to_string(event)
        # раскомментируйте строку  ниже, чтобы увидеть что происходит
        #print(f'------> {_key}, {event.text()}, {event.key()}, {_keys}')

        key = event.key()

        if self.prev_key:
            for k in self.prev_key:
                k.setStyleSheet("")

        if _keys[0] == 'Control' and key == Qt.Key_W:
            print(f'Нажали: {_key}')
            self.W.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.Ctrl.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Ctrl, self.W]
            # ...
        elif _keys[0] == 'Alt' and key == Qt.Key_W:
            print(f'Нажали: {_key}')
            self.W.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.Alt.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Alt, self.W]
            # ...
        elif _keys[0] == 'Shift' and key == Qt.Key_W:
            print(f'Нажали: {_key}')
            self.W.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.ShifL.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.ShifL, self.W]
            # ...

        elif key == Qt.Key_W:
            print('Нажали: w')
            self.W.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.W, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_A:
            print('Нажали: a')
            self.A.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.A, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_S:
            print('Нажали: s')
            self.S.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.S, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_D:
            print('Нажали: d')
            self.D.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.D, ]
            # ...
        elif key == Qt.Key_Escape:
            print('Нажали: Escape')
            self.esc.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.esc, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Tab:
            print('Нажали: Tab')
            self.Tab.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Tab, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Backspace:
            print('Нажали: Backspace')
            self.Backspace.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Backspace, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Enter:  # Обычно находится на клавиатуре.
            print('Нажали: Enter')
            self.Enter.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Enter, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Return:
            print('Нажали: Enter/Return')
            self.Enter.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Enter, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_QuoteLeft:
            print('Нажали: A_10/QuoteLeft(`)')
            self.A_10.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.A_10, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Delete:
            print('Нажали: Delete')
            self.dlt.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.dlt, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Shift:
            print('Нажали: Shift')
            self.ShifL.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.ShiftR.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.ShifL, self.ShiftR]
            time.sleep(60)
            self.ShifL.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.ShiftR.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.prev_key = [self.ShifL, self.ShiftR]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Control:  # В macOS это соответствует клавишам Command.
            print('Нажали: Ctrl')
            self.Ctrl.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Ctrl, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Alt:
            print('Нажали: Alt')
            self.Alt.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc; color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Alt, ]
        elif key == Qt.Key_Meta:
            print('Нажали: Windows ')
            self.Win.setStyleSheet(" color: red;")
            self.prev_key = [self.Win, ]

    def keyevent_to_string(self, event):
        sequence = []
        for modifier, text in modmap.items():
            if event.modifiers() & modifier:
                sequence.append(text)
        key = keymap.get(event.key(), event.text())
        if key not in sequence:
            sequence.append(key)
        return '+'.join(sequence), sequence


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]